# Multiple or Conditional Configuration Parameters

Tags: ros, parameter, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

First of all, I must say that I'm not sure how to organize/design this.
So, I'm going to explain it with an example:

I have an application that detects features using OpenCV features detectors. I've allowed to dynamically reconfigure the feature detector (one of: SURF, SIFT, GFTT, ...), coding a **cfg** file as explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode).

Now I want to do the same for the parameters of each feature detectors, but I'm not sure what can I do with ROS support.

1. Could I make the parameters of each feature detector to appear (in **reconfiguregui**) conditionally, depending on the current feature detector selected?
2. If not, is it possible (appropiate) to have serveral **cfg** files in a single package? I think, this way I could run several instances of **reconfiguregui**, one for a feature detector.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9549/multiple-or-conditional-configuration-parameters/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Dynamic reconfigure currently does not support hiding parameters based on other settings. That would be wonderful to have. There is an [enhancement ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/3617) requesting it.
2. It *is* possible for a package to contain several **cfg** files. And, it must also be possible to access them somehow from within a single node, since nodelets can do that. I don't know exactly how to do it, but would suggest experimenting with defining each callback in a separate subordinate namespace.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-04-25**:
Each callback in a separate subordinate namespace works, even with a single-threaded spinner. Thanks!